# updatepanel works once then submits the page (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an updatepanel which after clicking one button is submitting the page. The code is

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlCalendar" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="panCalendarHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button id="btnViewWholeWeek" text="View Whole Week" runat="server" CssClass="normal-button" OnClick="viewWholeWeek" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>
    </ContentTemplate>   
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

the function on press contains no code as I've been testing with out that to see if it was causing the problem. Here is it anyway

```
protected void viewWholeWeek(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    HtmlContainerControl paraDayName = (HtmlContainerControl)new HtmlGenericControl("p");
    paraDayName.InnerHtml = "test";
    panCalendarHolder.Controls.Add(paraDayName); 
}
```

I press the button above once... it works - refreshing the updatepanel. I press it again and it submits the page. I have everything inside a `<form id="frmMain" runat="server">` and `</form>` tag....

any ideas?!

Comment: What does `submits the page` mean? Every postback submits the page even asynchronous. Are you aware that you need to recreate every dynamically created control on every postback manually in page_load at the latest? Otherwise it will not be recreated.

Comment: The first click of the button does an async, then the second time you click it, it submits the entire page. Ie: not the updatepanel. The buttons are not dynamically created - they are in the standard HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, there is no problem in there at all... maybe you give us more details! What do you do in Page_load function?

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer simply because it prompted me to review the code in page_load. I was doing some trickery which forced a redirect if a variable wasn't being set. IsPostBack to the rescue.

Comment: I consider **IsPostBack** as a must property in almost all pages :) I am glad my simple comment helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try with `updateMode = Conditional` in your Update panel class. As you know by default it's value is Always.

Answer (score 0):

This is some common bug that is fixed with the adding of this boilerplate code:

```
private void EnsureUpdatePanelFixups()
{
    if (this.Page.Form != null)
    {
        string formOnSubmitAtt = this.Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"];

        if (formOnSubmitAtt == "return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();")
        {
            this.Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = "_spFormOnSubmitWrapper();";
        }
    }

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(ThisClassTypeGoesHere), "SomeStringToBeTheKey", "_spOriginalFormAction = document.forms[0].action;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;", true);
}
```

Make sure that gets called every postback. I got that from a co-worker, so I can't site a source, sorry.

Comment: I've actually only worked on SharePoint, never just ASP, so probably.